# How to combine completable with Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to make changes to existing flow of data loading such that I call a new cache API without changing any logical change to anything else.

I have a observable variable of type Weather. I want to call another Completable API which simply stores a boolean in the shared preference. This new API is completable as I don't expect any result from it.

How can I add this completable call to the observable so whenever someone subscribes to the observable, I simply execute the completable.

```
fun fetchWeather(): Observable<Weather> {
return weatherObservable
.startWithItem(
    // Weather Object
  )
}

fun hasWeatherFetched(): Completable {
   // Call shared preference
}
```

Comment: It depends on how your flow is organized; could be either `flatMapCompletable`, `andThen`, etc. Please share code examples of what you have.

Comment: `fun fetchWeather(): Observable<Weather> {

    return weatherObservable

    .startWithItem(

        // Weather Object
    )
}

fun hasWeatherFetched(): Completable {
    // Call shared preference
}`

This is what I have. I don't want to change the return type of fetchWeather method

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve here. `Completable` does not produce any results. You can use `toObservable()` to convert it back.

Comment: I have a consumer, which consumes Observable<Weather> which is coming from a rest api call. Let's say this call is simply printing the two weather(one from rest and other from startWithItem). Now all I want is to add a call to sharedPreference which is a Completable call and it should happen exactly once when the server has returned data in the rest call. 

If I call completable.toObservable() the consumer of Observable<Weather> is getting no items.

Comment: Try `fetchWeather().concatWith(hasWeatherFetched().<Weather>toObservable())`.